# Get count of documents in sub-sites

Tags: 2013, javascript

There's many resources explaining how to list sub-sites in site collections using javascript. Is there a way to list all document libraries and count of documents within every sub-site ?
So for every sub-site I'd like to report document library name and a count of documents within. Is there a property to reveal this information?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Load the library as an object first, then load it's 'Items' property into another variable. Use the 'count' method against 'Items' and you should get the number of items.